# How to use profiles with Tor Browser?

Tags: firefox, terminal, shell, troubleshooting, tor

Firefox allows for the ability to use multiple profiles by starting the browser from the command line as such:
`firefox --ProfileManager`
Or more directly:
`firefox --CreateProfile`

However, despite being included in `tor --help` , these commands do not work when I replace `firefox` with `tor`. The browser starts normally without any other options.

Is there a workaround to navigate this important Firefox functionality to the Tor Browser? I'm running Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: I too am looking for the same answer. At least an alternate way to achieve the same effect? Please don't say vpn.